# Как изменить количество цифр?

Tags: javascript, html, комбинаторика

Есть код, который создаёт строки такого вида:

**5 чисел пробел одно дополнительное число (`x-x-x-x-x x`)**,

а нужно сделать

**5 чисел и 5 дополнительных чисел (`x-x-x-x-x x-x-x-x-x x`)**.

Считать одной комбинацией набор из ***5*** основных чисел и ***5*** дополнительных.

Основные числа с дополнительными в ***1*** комбинации ***1*** раз могут повторится за запрос. Одна комбинация с другой комбинацией за один запрос на любое количество комбинаций повторяться не должны.

```js
function  generate() {
 document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "";
      const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
      let resultSet = new Map();
      let qnt = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);
      while (resultSet.size < qnt) {
        let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
        let key = (nums.sort() + '');
        resultSet.set(key, nums);
      }
      resultSet.forEach(val => {
        const main = createTableWithContent(val.join('-'), "one");
        const additional = createTableWithContent(randInt(), "two");
        main.append(additional);
        document.getElementById("myTable").append(main);
      })
    }
    
    function shuffle(arr) {
      return arr.map(el => {
        return {
          item: el,
          sort: Math.random()
        }
      }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
    }
    
    function randInt(min = 1, max = 4) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    
    function createTableWithContent(content, className) {
      const tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
      tableEl.className = className || "";
      tableEl.append(content);
      return tableEl;
      
    }
```

```html
<input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Кол-во комбинаций" style="background: #ffffff!important;color: #8f2d00!important;font-size: 20px!important;"/><input class="annoying-btn" type="button" value="Получить комбинации" onclick="generate()" />
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы после тире генерировалось тоже 5 цифр, а не одно как сейчас?

Comment: вы потрудитесь хотя бы написать, что данный код решает, а не только "есть код". с таким описанием вопроса мало, кто захочет вам помочь. да и в целом, не мешало бы объяснить в чем у вас сложности с доработкой этого кода

Comment: сигнатуру `randInt` замените на `randInt(min = 10000, max = 99999)` и будет вам 5 цифр

Comment: Если под "после тире" подразумевается вторая строка в выводе

Comment: @teran Сейчас код генерирует цифры вида ххххх-х, а надо ххххх-хxxxx и основное, чтобы левые цифры не совпадали с правыми, то-бишь не было так чтобы во всех комбинациях левые цифры совпадали с правыми. Условно, ставлю 100 комбинаций и не было  во всех комбинациях одних и тех же цифр.

Comment: @teran не должно быть так 0104050811-2345296501  0104050811-2345296501  0104050811-2345296501  0104050811-2345296501

Comment: @teran вид у правого числового значения должен быть такой же как и у левого, то-бишь если это число 1 то должно быть 01 и так далее, цифры должны разделяться через тире

Comment: @teran вот такой вид комбинации должны принять https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6Z4R/9ETFDHXoV

Comment: @teran Исправил наверху задание

Comment: Все равно ничего не понятно. Приведите в вопросе примеры валидного результата, и невалидного

Comment: Кажется, я понял: вы хотите получить уникальные последовательности из 10 чисел, где каждая последовательность разбита на две группы, внутри которых может быть только одно совпадение, так?

Comment: @ThisMan все верно, но у левой группы с правой могут быть повторения, то- бишь группы должны быть независимы друг от друга

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надеюсь, что я вас правильно понял. Я сделал вам так, что теперь в начале создаётся каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку новая таблица и в неё заносятся новые строчки. Старая таблица при этом удаляется. Таблица теперь всегда одна, а строк в ней сколько вам угодно. У вас в коде вы неверно добавляли множество таблиц.

Ваш `Map` `resultSet` я заменил на обычный массив, т.к. в `Map` я не вижу надобности. Да и вообще даже и массив здесь не нужен, т.к. можно заполнять таблицу напрямую, но в этом случае придётся вам добавить переменную `counter` вместо `result.length` в `while`. Но я этот массив оставил, чтобы вам было привычнее и понятней.

**Решение**

```js
var tableEl;
 
function generate()
{    
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable"),
        numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i),
        result = [],
        qnt = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);

    myTable.innerHTML = '';
    tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
    myTable.appendChild(tableEl);

    while(result.length < qnt)
    {
        var left = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5).join('-'),
            right = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5).join('-');

        //чтобы не были равны между собой
        if(left == right)
            continue;

        result.push([left, right]);
        fillTableWithContent(left + ' ' + right);
    }
}

function shuffle(arr)
{
    return arr.map(el => {
        return {
            item: el,
            sort: Math.random()
        }
    }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}

function fillTableWithContent(content)
{
    tableEl.insertRow(tableEl.rows.length)
        .insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
}
```

```html
<input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Кол-во комбинаций"/>
<input type="button" value="Получить комбинации" onclick="generate()"/>
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Если что-то непонятно – спрашивайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, то что нужно. Ответ принят!

Comment: Единственная просьба, как мне визуально разделить левую с правой Стилями?

Comment: @Arcadiy, я хотел так сразу сделать, но вы написали, что нужен пробел. В общем надо изменить функцию `fillTableWithContent` вот на такую: `function fillTableWithContent(first, second)
{
 var row = tableEl.insertRow(tableEl.rows.length);
 row.insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode(first));
 row.insertCell(1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(second));
}`